# Error in tensorflow placeholder.

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am using a Alexnet, finetuned on flowers data with 5 classes. Now, I want to predict using the fine tuned model. The below shown is the main code.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime
from alexnet_flower import AlexNet
from datagenerator import ImageDataGenerator

from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy.misc import imresize
import time
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy.ndimage import filters
import urllib
from numpy import random
from numpy import *
import os
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saver_pb2

im1 = (imread("one.png")[:,:,:3]).astype(float32)
#print(im1.shape())
im1 = im1 - mean(im1)
#im1 = imresize(im1,[227,227,3])
im1[:, :, 0], im1[:, :, 2] = im1[:, :, 2], im1[:, :, 0]

im2 = (imread("two.png")[:,:,:3]).astype(float32)
im2 = im2 - mean(im2)
#im2 = imresize(im2,[227,227,3])
im2[:, :, 0], im2[:, :, 2] = im2[:, :, 2], im2[:, :, 0]

"""
Configuration settings
"""

print(im1.shape)
num_classes  = 5
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 227, 227, 3])
#y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

#print(x)

# Initialize model
model = AlexNet(x,keep_prob,num_classes)

# Link variable to model output
score = model.fc8

saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)

#x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,) + xdim)

with tf.Session() as sess:

  # Initialize all variables
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # Add the model graph to TensorBoard

  # Load the pretrained weights into the non-trainable layer
  saver.restore(sess,"/home/saurabh/deep_learning/tests/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/model_epoch1.ckpt")
 # x1:[im1,im2]
  print('error!!!!!!')

  output = sess.run(score, feed_dict = {x:[im1,im2]})
```

The code I am using this code for [alexnet](https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/blob/master/alexnet.py). I think there is no issue with the alexnet code, because I fine-tuned using this code.

Finally I got this error. I tried a lot to debug it, I am unable to understand the problem. Thanks for any help.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finetune_prediction_flowers.py", line 81, in <module>
    output = sess.run(score, feed_dict = {x:[im1,im2]})
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder_1', defined at:
  File "finetune_prediction_flowers.py", line 56, in <module>
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1587, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2043, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Meaning: you must feed a value to the placeholder `keep_prob`, because you request `score` in your call to `sess.run`, which in turn requires `keep_prob` to have a value. So just set the keep probability to the value you want (here e.g. 0.8):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
  # Load the pretrained weights into the non-trainable layer
  saver.restore(sess,"/home/saurabh/deep_learning/tests/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/model_epoch1.ckpt")    
  output = sess.run(score, feed_dict = {x:[im1,im2], keep_prob: 0.8})
```

By the way: If you are restoring from a checkpoint, there is no need to call `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

Comment: Thanks! at least the error is gone. Can you please tell me what does this probability score is used for? Also, what changes should I make in code to get the probability value for each class for the particular image rather than score because earlier I used the same code to get probability values. thanks in advance!

Comment: I got the change I have to make to get the probability. Can you just tell me why do give probability value here, what's the use of it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know `AlexNet` but usually the keep probability refers to dropout regularization. During dropout, a unit is kept (i.e. unchanged) with probability `keep_prob` and dropped with probability `1 - keep_prob`. Usually dropout is only used during training, so at test time consider disabling dropout, i.e. setting `keep_prob` to 1.0. But again, you will have to check the implementation of `AlexNet` to be sure this parameter refers to dropout regularization.